# I can't get the bibtex style I want to

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, packages

I'd really really appreciate your help. I am trying to change my bibliography style (preferably to [the AER style](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic?lang=en)) but I have no idea how to get the style I want to or even something close. I also don't know how to get have latex drop the numbers in front of each reference in the bibliography. The problem is that I am using this template for a dissertation....  I think it was just this template here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/georgia-tech-phd-thesis-template/hhvftnrbspbk

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}   %12 point font for Times New Roman
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=authoryear, natbib]{biblatex}  %reference manager
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Add your bibliography file here
\bibliography{myjabrefbib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title Page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\input{titlePage.tex}
\currentpdfbookmark{Title Page}{titlePage}  %add PDF bookmark for this page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% References
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{singlespace}  % use single-line spacing for multi-line text within a single reference
    \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}  %manually set separataion betwen items in bibliography to double space
    \printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The bibliography style file `aer.bst` requires BibTeX, not biblatex/biber. Are you able to switch to BibTeX?

Comment: yes, I'm able to switch to bibtex instead of biber as backend.